# Apache Tika Server Password protected pdf file parsing

Tags: .net-core, pdfbox, apache-tika, pdf-parsing, tika-server

I am using Tika server 2.5, when trying to parse pdf document which is password protected getting exeption of
**EncryptedDocumentException**, so is their any way to parse this document or send the password to tika server for parsing?

Comment: As per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1494 what happens if you pass the password along in the `Password` HTTP header with the request?

Comment: tried with adding non standard Http request header as below but still having same issue. -->  var client=new HttpClient();                       var stream=File.OpenRead(fileName);       
var content=new MultipartForm DataContent{{new StreamContent(stream) }};  HttpRequestMessage request=new HttpRequestMessage(){              requestUri= new Uri("Your Endpoints Address"), Method= HttpMethod.Post,               
 Headers={{"X-Password", "Password"}}, 
content=content    };                                                        
HttpResponseMessage response= client.SendAsync(request).Result;

Comment: @Gagravarr any other apporaches which we can do?

Comment: My understanding from reading that issue is that it's "Password" and not "X-Password". Like it's done in this unit test: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tika/trunk/tika-server/src/test/java/org/apache/tika/server/MetadataResourceTest.java?r1=1646707&r2=1646706&pathrev=1646707

Comment: @TilmanHausherr As it is non standard Http request header followed naming convention.tried with Password text as well but still the same issue.

Comment: I just answered in the mailing list where you also posted. I got it to work with "Password".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it worked for me by using the header `Password`:

Curl -T "Simple-40-bit-RC4-encrypted.pdf" http://localhost:9998/rmeta/form --header "Password:1234567890abcdefghijk1234567890abcdefghijk"