# Tika server cant parse text from encrypted doc

Tags: apache-tika, tika-server

Any files saved from libreOffice (odt or docx etc) that is encrypted by password produce such an exception on tika server

```
WARN  [qtp310212872-45] 08:52:13,393 org.apache.tika.server.core.resource.TikaResource tika/text: Text extraction failed (null)
org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: TIKA-198: Illegal IOException from org.apache.tika.parser.odf.OpenDocumentParser@6bc5bd75
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:304) ~[tika-server-standard-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:298) ~[tika-server-standard-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:203) ~[tika-server-standard-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.tika.server.core.resource.TikaResource.parse(TikaResource.java:357) ~[tika-server-standard-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.tika.server.core.resource.TikaResource.parseToMetadata(TikaResource.java:611) ~[tika-server-standard-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.tika.server.core.resource.TikaResource.getJson(TikaResource.java:581) ~[tika-server-standard-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at...
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: only DEFLATED entries can have EXT descriptor
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC(ZipInputStream.java:312) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:124) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tika.parser.odf.OpenDocumentParser.handleZipStream(OpenDocumentParser.java:219) ~[tika-server-standard-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.tika.parser.odf.OpenDocumentParser.parse(OpenDocumentParser.java:170) ~[tika-server-standard-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:298) ~[tika-server-standard-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    ... 43 more
```

TIKA-198 - is old closed issue

And also i cant unpack any zip, even if i send any password. Return 204 no content for such a zip files (Password is correct)

P.S. Header "Password" is used when i send request to server

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using?

Comment: @Gagravarr 2.9.1.0

Comment: @Gagravarr and also i cant unpack any zip, even if i send any password. Return 204 no content for such a zip files (Password is correct)

Comment: @Gagravarr ? Any suggessions ?

Comment: It ought to work - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74119481/685641 for an example